# Is it possible to create "stacked" bar with data grouped by 2 columns?

Tags: .net, charts

i have a dataset like below

```
Col1        Col2       Col3
__________________________
Product1    Region1    23
Product1    Region1    34
Product1    Region2    45
Product2    Region1    12
Product2    Region2    33
Product2    Region1    33
```

....

I want to create a stacked bar with Col1 in X-axis, SUM(Col3) in Y-axis, but sum values in Y-axis must be stacked by Col2.

How can i manage this with ASP.NET 3.5 Charts?